# Compress .mp3 for iPhone game?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, mp3

I have some music files for my cocos2d game and they're all quite big 5-6MB mp3 files. I'd like to keep the app file size down so is there a way I can compress them further? i.e. converting to .caf?

I'm only playing one track at a time.

Comment: What bitrates are you using? Are your files stereo? You can compress MP3 a lot if you can lose some quality.

Comment: Just so it's clear, MP3 is a compressed file format already. @jv42 has some good advice otherwise

Comment: You can resample the MP3 with a lower bitrate. Any decent audio processing tool does that. Try Audacity for example, or SoundConverter if you just need a conversion tool.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the MP3 file length in many parts and use that in sequence and if the file audio length is not much you can reduce the sample rate Like :

currently - 300kb/sec you can reduce it to 50 or 100 kb/sec this Will reduce the size but effect the quality of the music audio.

Thanks